# Pandas wide format transpose to long format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this, with an ID column and a bunch of indicator columns(True/False):

```
df_have:

ID Male  Special_Need    Teeanger
1    T      F              T
2    F      T              F
```

I want to transpose it but only for attributes = True. i.e.

```
df_want:

ID  Attribute
1    Male
1    Teenager
2   Special_Need
```

Comment: `df.melt('ID').loc[lambda x : x['value']=='T'].drop('value',1).sort_values('ID')
` melt problem

Answer (score 2):

Using `melt`:

```
u = df.melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='Attribute')
u.loc[u.value.eq('T'), ['ID', 'Attribute']]
```

```
   ID     Attribute
0   1          Male
3   2  Special_Need
4   1      Teeanger
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `stack`

```
df.set_index('ID').rename_axis('Attribute',1).stack().loc[lambda x : x=='T'].reset_index().drop(0,1)
Out[268]: 
   ID     Attribute
0   1          Male
1   1      Teeanger
2   2  Special_Need
```